# Word Interop: How can I determine if a Word document selection includes a paragraph mark?

Tags: c#, vsto, selection, paragraph, word-interop

My `VSTO` Add-In provides a ribbon button that when clicked, calls `ObjButtonAddFoo_Click` which replaces the selected text with a literal string:

```
    private bool ReplaceText(string textToInsert)
    {
        bool retval = false;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;

        // if (currentSelection.ContainsTrailingParagraphMark)
        // {
        //    retval = true;
        // }

        currentSelection.Range.Text = textToInsert;
        currentSelection.EndKey(WdUnits.wdStory);

        return retval;
    }

    private void ObjButtonAddFoo_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ReplaceText("REPLACEMENT TEXT"))
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;
            currentSelection.TypeParagraph();
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

*Note: For the screen shot below, File->Options->Display->Show All Formatting Marks is checked.*

If the user selects text that includes a trailing paragraph mark:

[image]

then the paragraph mark is lost when the code `currentSelection.Range.Text = textToInsert` is executed. So, if the selection includes a trailing paragraph mark, I want to replace it by executing `currentSelection.TypeParagraph()`

I tried looking at currentSelection.Paragraphs.Count, but it's value is 1 whether or not the selection includes a paragraph mark.

I also tried the technique described in [How to: Programmatically exclude paragraph marks when creating ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-exclude-paragraph-marks-when-creating-ranges?view=vs-2019), but then if the selection does NOT include a trailing paragraph mark, the last character of the originally selected text is preserved. In other words, I still need to know if a trailing paragraph mark is in the selection.

```
    private bool ReplaceText(string textToInsert)
    {
        bool retval = false;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;

        // if (currentSelection.ContainsTrailingParagraphMark)
        // {
        //    retval = true;
        // }

        //Remove the paragraph mark from the range to preserve it
        object charUnit = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter;
        object move = -1;  // move left 1
        currentSelection.MoveEnd(ref charUnit, ref move);
        currentSelection.Range.Text = textToInsert;

        currentSelection.EndKey(WdUnits.wdStory);

        return retval;
    }
```

In my `ReplaceText` method, how do I determine if currentSelection has a trailing paragraph mark. Or, how do I retain the paragraph mark when `currentSelection.Range.Text = textToInsert` is executed?

Comment: You dealing with an unstable logic. My suggestion is to try the action **manually** then you **automate**. The good command instead of `Range.Text = or currentSelection.TypeParagraph()` use `Selection.TypeText()`. Let's try doing like you were typing on your keyboard ; in that case, **Word** take care of things ...

Answer (score 0):

I made this too hard. All I had to do was interrogate the last character of the selection to see if its a paragraph mark.

```
    private void ReplaceText(string textToInsert)
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-exclude-paragraph-marks-when-creating-ranges?view=vs-2019

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection;

        // if current selection has a trailing paragraph mark, then 
        // modify the selection to omit it before replacing the text
        if (currentSelection.Range.Text.Substring(currentSelection.Range.Text.Length-1, 1).Equals("\r"))
        {
            object charUnit = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter;
            object move = -1;
            currentSelection.MoveEnd(ref charUnit, ref move);
        }

        currentSelection.Range.Text = textToInsert;
    }
```